# Can't upload to BitBucket

Tags: push, bitbucket

I have a repository on BitBucket that has worked fine. But now I've added a second repository and followed the instructions on the repository set up page but get this response when I try to upload:

$ git push -u origin --all
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 23456: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Tried restarting SSH daemon, but no help.

I note that there was a problem of this nature a year ago reported on SE. But one would think it had been resolved by now.

Much appreciate insight and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Changed the query to https:...